# Return value based on closest number

Tags: javascript, function, filter

In the snippet you'll find a function that returns and outputs the distance belonging to a planet inside an array, based on what planet you type in `var found = getDistanceNumber('Saturn');`

I wanna use this code, not to return the distance of the planet as it's programmed now, but *the name of the planet closest to it*. So if I have Saturn as the parameter, I want it to check what its distance is, find the closest distance in the array, and output the planet belonging to that. In this case that'd be Jupiter.

How do I go about that?

```js
var data = [
 {
   "Planet": "Mercury",
   "Distance": "-92 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Venus",
   "Distance": "-42 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Earth",
   "Distance": "0"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Mars",
   "Distance": "78 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Jupiter",
   "Distance": "628 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Saturn",
   "Distance": "1,3 billion"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Uranus",
   "Distance": "2,7 billion"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Neptune",
   "Distance": "4, 3 billion"
 }
]


function getDistanceNumber(Planet) {
  return data.filter(
      function(data){return data.Planet == Planet}
  );
}

var found = getDistanceNumber('Mars');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=found[0].Distance;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can you count on the data being already sorted by distance as it is in your example? If so, once you find the first planet, get the planets at the index before and after and take the closest of the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you're aware I've made some fairly trivial updates to the data. I'm using "." as opposed to "," as the decimal separator. I've also removed the extra space in Neptune's distance as it looks like a typo in data entry.

---

I broke this into smaller problems. 
Namely, ...

- converting the distance strings into numerical values,
- getting a planet's object from its name string,
- calculating distances to the input,
- finding the smallest distance, and then
- using the smallest distance's index to find the name for the corresponding planet.

```js
console.clear()

// conver million/billion to numbers (in millions)
var conversionLUT = {'million': 1, 'billion': 1e3}

// convert distance string to number
function convertDistance(distStr){
  let dist = distStr.split(" ")
  return dist[0]*conversionLUT[dist[1]] || 0
}

// returns callback to calculate distance for a given planet
function distanceFrom(planetObj){
  return function(elem){
    return Math.abs(convertDistance(elem.Distance) - convertDistance(planetObj.Distance))
  }
}

// get object from array by planet name
function getPlanetObject(planetName, dat = data){
  return dat.find(d=>d.Planet === planetName)
}

// As one function
function findClosestPlanet(name, dat = data){
  // get distances given planet object
  let distances = dat.map(distanceFrom(getPlanetObject(name)))
  
  // smallest distance (filter out 0 to ignore self)
  let distToClosest = Math.min(...distances.filter(d => d>0))
  
  // find index of planet whose closest dist matches
  let indOfClosest = distances.findIndex(d=>d===distToClosest)
  
  // return planet name that is closest
  return data[indOfClosest].Planet
}

var data = [
 {
   "Planet": "Mercury",
   "Distance": "-92 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Venus",
   "Distance": "-42 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Earth",
   "Distance": "0"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Mars",
   "Distance": "78 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Jupiter",
   "Distance": "628 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Saturn",
   "Distance": "1.3 billion"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Uranus",
   "Distance": "2.7 billion"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Neptune",
   "Distance": "4.3 billion"
 }
]

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = findClosestPlanet('Saturn')
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution that save the previous planet then return it as result if the passed Planet in condition is matched :

```js
var data = [
 {
   "Planet": "Mercury",
   "Distance": "-92 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Venus",
   "Distance": "-42 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Earth",
   "Distance": "0"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Mars",
   "Distance": "78 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Jupiter",
   "Distance": "628 million"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Saturn",
   "Distance": "1,3 billion"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Uranus",
   "Distance": "2,7 billion"
 },
 {
   "Planet": "Neptune",
   "Distance": "4, 3 billion"
 }
]


function getClosestPlanet(Planet) {
  var previous_planet="";
  var result="";
  
  data.filter(function(data){
    if( data.Planet == Planet ) 
      result = previous_planet;
    else
      previous_planet = data.Planet;
  })  
  
  return result;
}

var found = getClosestPlanet('Saturn');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=found;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```